# App crashes if rotated on edit tags screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

App version: 1.0.27

If you are adding/editing tags on a question and your screen rotates, the app crashes. The logcat of the crash is posted below.

Logcat:

```
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stackexchange.marvin/com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.AskOrEditQuestionActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.AskFragment.getTags(AskFragment.java:357)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.AskOrEditQuestionActivity.getTagsArrayFromAskFragment(AskOrEditQuestionActivity.java:252)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.question.TagSearchFragment.onCreateView(TagSearchFragment.java:64)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:566)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at com.stackexchange.marvin.ui.TrackedSherlockFragmentActivity.onStart(TrackedSherlockFragmentActivity.java:26)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
03-26 01:33:00.314 E/AndroidRuntime(12181):     ... 13 more
03-26 01:33:00.314 W/ActivityManager(516):   Force finishing activity com.stackexchange.marvin/.ui.AskOrEditQuestionActivity
```

Answer (score 4):

Oh boy this took so much longer than I thought, but it's fixed and will be in the next build (1.0.28) coming out in the morning time EST tomorrow (3/27).

Answer (score 0):

Reproduced in v1.0.26 on a HTC One with Android 4.4.2. This looks pretty neat.

[image: a pretty jumbled screen with the error covered up by my own keyboard]

Comment: Nice and compact!